# $f(x)=0$ for $x\in X$, then $f(x) = 0$ for $x\in\overline{X}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove:

$f(x)=0$ for $x\in X$, then $f(x) = 0$ for $x\in\overline{X}$

where $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ **and is continuous**.

I know that the set $\overline{X}$ is the set of all points $a$ such that if $a\in I$, being $I$ open, then $I\cap X\neq \emptyset$.

I tried to assume that, since $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$, then I just need to find a sequence that approximates to $a\in\overline{X}$ such that $a\notin X$. Then I can use some property that will help me. However, I couldn't do it. Could you guys help me with something?

Comment: This isn't true if $f$ is not continuous

Comment: @AhmedHussein you're right, I corrected

Comment: Hint: $X \subseteq f^{-1}(\{0\})$

Comment: @AhmedHussein since $f$ is continuous, then $f(\overline{X})\subset \overline{f(f^{-1}(\{0\}))} = \overline{\{0\}}$?

Comment: nice, but do you have a more natural way? because the exercise that asks me to prove this property I used comes right after this one :c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $f$ is continuous and $\{0\}$ is closed, so $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed, so it is equal to its closure. Now,

$$X \subseteq f^{-1}(\{0\}) \implies \overline X \subseteq \overline{f^{-1}(\{0\})} = f^{-1}(\{0\})$$

thus, for all $x \in \overline X$, $f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A slick proof: a function $f$ is continuous iff the preimage under $f$ of any closed set is closed. Thus $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed. And since $X \subset f^{-1}(\{0\})$, we have $\overline{X} \subset \overline{f^{-1}(0)} = f^{-1}(0)$.

Your sequence argument also works. The topology of the real numbers is determined by its convergent sequences, and $f$ is continuous iff for every convergent sequence $(x_n) \to x$, $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. (Or, to write it neatly, $f(\lim x_n) = \lim f(x_n)$, i.e., $f$ commutes with limits.) By definition of $\overline{X}$, any point $x \in \overline{X}$ is the limit of a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements in $X$. But then $f(x) = f(\lim x_n) = \lim f(x_n) = \lim 0 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $a\in \overline X$ and any open set $I$ such that $a\in I$, $I\cap\overline X\ne \emptyset$. Since it is true for any such $I$, how can you choose a sequence $I_n$ so that $x_n\in I_n\cap\overline X$ approximates $a$?

**Hint**: Try $I_n:=(a-\frac 1n,a+\frac 1n)$.